# Circular panning with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I'm looking for a way to have interactive "circular panning" with matplotlib: when
interactively moving the axes to the left or the right, I want the data
(and axes labels) to "wrap around".  (An (silly) example application would
be e.g. plotting annual average temperatures, and wanting to look at
whether anything special is happening around New Year.)

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: You can try [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/). It's a interactive plotting tool based on Python.

Comment: Does Bokeh support this feature?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. Please check this [notebook](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/bokeh/bokeh-notebooks/blob/master/tutorial/02%20-%20plotting.ipynb). Is the lineplot inside it fit your target?

Comment: I'm looking for a graph like, say, http://www.eldoradocountyweather.com/forecast/climate/images/Sydney.png but with the possibility to pan left and right and having the data "reappear" from the other side.

Comment: Sorry, I clicked your link. But it shows like `Remote Linking Disable
`

Comment: Just imaging a random temperature vs. month of the year plot.

Comment: Sorry for my poor  comprehension. I searched `circular panning` on google.  Is the interact figure you want to plot based on the static figure like [this](http://www.tonmeister.ca/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/explanation.png). I can plot this kind of figure.